# Error message for empty field validation still showing after valid input in vue 3

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on developing some user forms. In my application, i am creating custom validation. It is working fine. But, error message for that empty field validation rule is still showing after any valid input.

I am not able to understand why that condition is not working.

// Validators.js

```
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
  errorMessage: '',
});
export default function useValidators() {
  const errorMessage = computed(() => state.errorMessage);
  const hasError = computed(() => !!state.errorMessage);
  const isEmpty = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
    if (!fieldValue) {
      state.errorMessage = `The ${fieldName} can not be empty`;
      return;
    }
    state.errorMessage = ''; 
  };
  return {
    isEmpty,
    errorMessage,
    hasError,
  };
}
```

Here is the form validation code.

```
    import { reactive } from 'vue';
import useValidators from './useValidators';

const errors = reactive({});
const { hasError, errorMessage, isEmpty } = useValidators();
export default function useFormValidation() {
  const validateInputField = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
    if (!fieldValue) {
      errors[fieldName] = isEmpty(fieldName, fieldValue);
    }
  };
  return {
    errors,
    isEmpty,
    validateInputField,
    errorMessage,
    hasError,
  };
}
```

This form validation js i am importing in my component like this way.

```
    <template>
<my-input-component :message-type="hasError && 'negative'"
           :message ="errorMessage">
  <label slot="label" for="example-input">Name of this place:</label>
  <input
      type="text"
      name="example-input"
      id="example-input"
      v-model="nameField"
      @keyup="validateInput"
      @blur="validateInput"
      />
</my-input-component>

</template>

<script setup>
import useFormValidation from '@/utilities/useFormValidation';


const nameField = ref('');
const {
  validateInputField, errorMessage, hasError,
} = useFormValidation();

const validateInput = () => {
  validateInputField('name', nameField.value);
};

</script>
```

I am not sure why this error message variable is not updating. That 'isEmpty' function what i have done wrong?